# how to decide if a poll result is Agreement or Argument?

Tags: polling

Let's say we have a poll with 3 possible choices (A - B - C). N people participated in the poll. A participant can participate only once by choosing only one choice of the available choices.

lets say:

the number of participants who voted for choice A is X.

the number of participants who voted for choice B is Y.

the number of participants who voted for choice C is Z.

so X+Y+Z=N (total participants).

for example

case1: if X=800 Y=80 Z=120 => "**Agreement**" on choice A.

case2: if X=400 Y=450 Z=150 => "**Argument**" on choices A and B.

case3: if X=334 Y=333 Z=333 => "**Argument**" on choices A, B and C.

case4: if X=166 Y=334 Z=500 => Not "**Agreement**" nor "**Argument**"

Now the question is: Which formula to use to decide if a poll result is **Agreement** (like case 1) or **Argument** (like case 2 and case 3)?

The standard deviation is not enough in my case because:

The standard deviation for case 1 = 33.03

The standard deviation for case 2 = 13.12

The standard deviation for case 3 = 0.04

The standard deviation for case 4 = 13.63

I could not decide on case 2 and case 4 using The standard deviation.

Comment: Your definitions of various types of 'Agreement' are not clear.

Comment: I think (@usama can correct) @usama wants to know what a good definition for distinctions would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One traditional method of analysis would be to use a chi squared test see whether the choices A, B, and C are
significantly different in popularity.

For example, suppose there X = (166, 334, 400), respectively, choosing A,B,and C.
With 900 subjects and equally popular choices, we would expect $E =300$ of each to be chosen.

Then we could to a chi-squared test
to test whether or not there are significant differences in popularity.  Using R:

```
X = c(166. 334. 400);  E = c(300, 300, 300)
```

The chi-squared statistic is

$$H = \sum_{i=1}^3 \frac{(X_i-E_i)^2}{E_i} = 97.04.$$
Under the null hypothesis that choices are equally likely,
we have $H\stackrel{aprx}{\sim} \mathsf{Chisq}(\nu = 2).

```
chisq.test(X)

        Chi-squared test for given probabilities

data:  X
X-squared = 97.04, df = 2, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

The null hypothesis is rejected at the 5% level with P-value near $0 < 0.05.$
Unless something else is specified, the 'given probabilities' assumed to be equal.)
The squares of the Pearson residuals sum to $H,$ according to the formula
displayed above. They are obtained in R as follows:

```
chisq.test(X)$resi
[1] -7.736494  1.962991  5.773503
```

From the residuals with largest absolute values, we see that numbers of choices for A and C are very far from their expected
counts of $300$ each.

So it seems worthwhile to look at just those two categories:

```
chisq.test(c(166, 400))

        Chi-squared test for given probabilities

data:  c(166, 400)
X-squared = 96.742, df = 1, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

A test of binomial proportions (without continuity dorrection)
does the same test, but with additional output. In particular, we see that
proportions 0.293 and 0.707 (out of 556) are significantly different.

```
prop.test(c(166,400), c(566, 566), corr=F)

        2-sample test for equality of proportions 
        without continuity correction

data:  c(166, 400) out of c(566, 566)
X-squared = 193.48, df = 1, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.4664699 -0.3603852
sample estimates:
   prop 1    prop 2 
0.2932862 0.7067138
```

If you do very many of these *ad hoc* tests after the main
chi-squared test, then you should use some method (such as
Bonferron's) to avoid 'false discovery'. but above the P-values
are so small that there is little danger of false dixcovery.